# update of entity with hibernate entity manager

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have one implementation where my entity `Company` extends `RootEntity` with

```
strategy =InheritanceType.JOINED.(I am using hibernate-entitymanager)
```

I have other entities which does not extends `RootEntity`. When I create all entites it does create.But when I try to update an extended entity of `RootEntity`,it does not update. But the non extending entity is updating. The update code is in `GenericDaoImpl` so it is the same update method.

what can be the problem?  my code is:

```
@Transactional(value="tx")
public E update(E entity) {
    E merged = null;
    RootEntity baseEntity = null;
    if(entity instanceof RootEntity ){
        baseEntity = (RootEntity)entity;
        merged = entityManager.find(entityClass, baseEntity.getId());
    }
    merged = entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
    return merged;
}
```

My Object That I am trying to merge:

```
public class Societa extends RootEntity implements Serializable{

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     // ASSOCIAZIONE CAMPI DB VARIABILI NELLA CLASSE
     @Column(name="nomeSocieta",nullable = false,columnDefinition="CHAR(80)")
     private String nomeSocieta;

      ......
}
```

and my RootEntity is:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy =InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class RootEntity {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Id
       @Column(name="id",nullable = false)
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long id;
        ...getters/setters..
   }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the object you are trying to merge that doesn't work? Do you get an error message or you just don't see any change in the database?

Comment: hi, I have added some code samples, it does not give any error,just it does not update

Comment: don't just say that, tell us how you solved it. This forum is to help  all, not just   you

Answer (score 0):

Newaz, I need to see your `RootEntity` and `Company` entity.

Also, I was having hard time understanding your provided code though -

1. Why you need that "if" condition? and what will happen if that if is not true?
2. `entityManager.flush();` you don't have to do this, if i understand correctly, you are using spring and `@Transactional` automatically closes/flushes transaction when invoked method is finished.